# Halftone Shading in Photoshop (adobe tutorial help)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, halftone

I've been having difficulty replicating these halftone shades in this tutorial on Page 5: http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/files/2014/01/Reality-Reborn-How-To.pdf

I have two problems with this section:

1) My dots aren't as fine as the example, could this be the initial size of the shape?

2) When I import the bitmap tiff into Illustrator, it looks bad, because the screen resolution changes the appearance of the bitmap i.e. It doesn't look smooth, like in the example.

I've looked elsewhere on the net and here - couldn't find a similar issue, so hopefully this will help others! Many thanks for looking into this - there's obviously workarounds and other methods, but I would like to know this one specifically.

If you don't understand, then I can post an example when I get home.

Comment: Read the tutorial but didn't do it myself, but based on what I read I'd think size would play a role.

Answer (score 1):

The higher the resolution of your gradient image is, the higher you can set `Max. Radius` (in `Filters > Pixelate > Color Halftone`) and the smooter the dots will get.